# Which of gcc's -O3 optimization flags enable "hardware accelerated instructions"

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

So basically, for my project, there is a restriction that it must not use the -O3 flag (we must only use -O2). The reasoning for this is that the -O3 flag apparently introduces "hardware accelerated  instructions".

The gcc version is 5.4 and the manual page for this version's optimization flags is: [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

I want to include as many of -O3's flags as possible.
The list of flags introduced by -O3 are:

```
-finline-functions, -funswitch-loops, -fpredictive-commoning, -fgcse-after-reload, -ftree-loop-vectorize, -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns, -ftree-slp-vectorize, -fvect-cost-model, -ftree-partial-pre and -fipa-cp-clone
```

So I am planning to use -O2 and manually include as many of the above flags as possible.

Which flags above enable "hardware accelerated instructions" optimizations? How can I tell if a flag enables "hardware accelerated instructions" optimizations by reading the descriptions? What constitutes that?

Comment: Basically anything with vectorizing is likely taking advantage of specific hardware support to work faster than the "simple" element by element instructions, but I'm a little unclear on the problem here. "Hardware enabled instructions" describes literally every instruction; it has to run on an actual chip (or software simulating such a chip on another chip), it's not magic.

Comment: In short: What are you really trying to avoid here?

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry, I meant "hardware ACCELERATED instructions". Edited the question to reflect this change

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am trying to speed up my program by using as many of -O3's flags as possible (those that do not enable hardware accelerated instructions), in combination with -O2

Comment: All instructions are "hardware accelerated." The run on the hardware.

Comment: You really should tell us more about why you cannot use whatever instructions you are not supposed to use to get a proper answer.

Comment: It is a rule set for the lab assignment by the TA. We cannot use hardware accelerated instructions. (They gave an example like how -O3 enables SSE instructions which we cannot use). @Ivan

Comment: I am not sure what kind of assignment this can be - I don't see why would such restriction be needed. But compiler if free to use any instructions even with -O2 and will surely use them. You should check John's answer, it explains your situation.

Comment: Because it is a competition between members of the class as to who creates the fastest program and the TA's just want to restrict it for some reason. @Ivan also the answer below does not really answer my question tbh as good-natured as it is. I am asking which optimizations from that list above enable hardware accelerated instructions

Comment: @Bob none of them. Compiler already uses "hardware accelerated instructions" at -O2. I think the answer below does a good job at explaining this. Check this code: https://ideone.com/UWyQtC and try to build it with GCC at -O2 at https://godbolt.org/. You can see it generates SSE instructions even at -O2 level.

Comment: If not using `-O3` is one of the rules of the contest, maybe you need to talk with your instructor about what optimization flags _are_ allowable. It may be risky to attempt to guess what the instructor has in mind.

Comment: is your lab still using Pentium II CPUs? SSE was available for nearly 2 decades. Otherwise the lab operators doesn't have any idea about computer architecture

Comment: technically almost every instruction is "hardware accelerated instruction" because all of them are done in hardware. You can do additions with `inc` or `lea` or even `sub`. Likewise all bitwise operations can be done with a single `nand` or `nor`... So why bother adding more instructions? Because they all help accelerating the programs

Answer (score 4):

The set of instructions used is controlled by `-march`, not by `-O3`.  It is true that `-O3` may make more use of SIMD instructions for vectorization, but `-O3` does not specifically add or remove instructions from consideration during code generation.

If you want to compile your code with the simplest instructions only, choose the simplest `march` for your platform.  For example, `-march=core2` would be a conservative choice for x86-64, as this refers to the Intel Core 2 processor family which is quite old.

Still, Core 2 supports MMX and SSE to SSE3 and SSSE3.  To disable those, add:

```
-mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -mno-ssse3
```

Comment: My TA said "Using -O3 enables hardward accelerated instructions such as SSE". Since the lab handout said we cannot use HAI, we cannot use -O3. I want to know which optimizations from the list above I can/cannot use

Comment: @Bob: Your TA is wrong. SSE is enabled below `-O3`, since compiling for 64 bit x86-64 CPUs already guarantees at least some SSE instructions are available (the oldest x86-64 CPUs guaranteed up to SSE2 IIRC). You'd need to explicitly disable them as John suggested, or the compiler will use them freely at `-O2`.

Comment: I don't think most of the code would even compile with `-mno-sse` for x86-64 as ABI requires SSE registers.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like John has already answered this question, I will try to provide some examples.

Consider following minimal program:

```
#include <cstring>

void copy(long *dst , const long *src)
{
    std::memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(long) * 4);
}
```

Compiled with GCC 7.2 `g++ -O2` at x86_64 gives following output:

```
copy(long*, long const*):
  movdqu (%rsi), %xmm0
  movups %xmm0, (%rdi)
  movdqu 16(%rsi), %xmm0
  movups %xmm0, 16(%rdi)
  ret
```

Compiled with GCC 7.2 `g++ -O2 -mno-sse` at x86_64 gives following output:

```
copy(long*, long const*):
  movq (%rsi), %rax
  movq %rax, (%rdi)
  movq 8(%rsi), %rax
  movq %rax, 8(%rdi)
  movq 16(%rsi), %rax
  movq %rax, 16(%rdi)
  movq 24(%rsi), %rax
  movq %rax, 24(%rdi)
  ret
```

As you can see, GCC is able to generate SSE instructions even at `-O2` level. Separate flag is required to suppress generation of those instructions.

At the same time GCC 5.4 generates the same code with and without `-mno-sse` flag, but it also does the same for `-O3` optimization level.

So your goal is a bit misleading here. Using superset of `-O2` flags might suppress generation of SSE and similar instructions in some cases, but this is not guaranteed as optimization level is only indirectly related to what instructions are generated. If you really want to suppress those, you can use `-mno-sse` flag, but this will probably put you at disadvantage. Just stick with `-O2` - this way everyone will be on equal terms.

I used https://godbolt.org/ to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a couple.

Your TA said:

> Using -O3 enables hardward accelerated instructions such as SSE

I think that's not really correct. It seems like -f options are intended to be machine-independent. A compiler parses the source code and transforms it into, generally, something called intermediate representations (IRs). Following that, a compiler optimizes IR itself so-called machine-independently. Then, the assembly code is generated from the optimized IR. When the assembly is generated, a different set of optimizations are applied. Examples of IR would be LLVM IR, Sun IR, GCC gimple tree and/or RTL, etc. I believe all modern compiler have IR(s).

GCC's -f options are, I believe, basically intended to be machine-independent. -m options are for machine-dependent optimizations. -O2 or -O3 determines -f options, which are ideally machine-independent. Using fancy instructions is up to machine-dependent parts of a compiler.

In reality, the boarder line between machine-dependent and machine-independent worlds might not be crystal clear.

Vectorization turned on by -O3 would be an example of optimizations in a gray area. Some machines do not support SIMD. Some do but the vector size, for example, is different from architecture to architecture. Here is my example code:

```
// code.c
long long int inner_product(int* v0, int* v1, int sz) {
    long long int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        res += (v0[i] * v1[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

If it is compiled as follows:

```
$ gcc  -O3 -S -march=core2  code.c  -o code.s  -fdump-tree-all
```

Gcc vectorizes it but the vector size is 2 long long ints or 4 ints:

```
$ cat code.*.optimized | grep 'vector('
vector(2) long long int vect_res_16.21;
vector(2) long long int vect_res_16.19;
vector(2) long long int vect__8.18;
vector(4) int vect__7.17;
vector(4) int vect__6.16;
vector(4) int * vectp_v1.15;
vector(4) int vect__4.13;
vector(4) int * vectp_v0.12;
```

On the other hands, if it is compiled with -march=skylake-avx512, whose vector size is 4 times bigger than core2, the outcome would be:

```
$ gcc  -O3 -S -march=skylake-avx512  code.c  -o code.s  -fdump-tree-all && cat code.*.optimized | grep 'vector('
vector(8) long long int vect_res_16.21;
vector(8) long long int vect_res_16.19;
vector(8) long long int vect__8.18;
vector(16) int vect__7.17;
vector(16) int vect__6.16;
vector(16) int * vectp_v1.15;
vector(16) int vect__4.13;
vector(16) int * vectp_v0.12;
```

Note that the code generation did not yet start at this point. The IR looks different depending on the march value. I guess vectorization is not the only example that shows this kind of behavior.

Nonetheless, I do not think that it is fair to call such optimizations machine-dependent. A typical machine dependent optimization is instruction scheduling. It has almost nothing to do with intermediate representations. It is more about machine instructions and the micro-architecture. For those machine-independent optimizations in a gray area, conceptually, a compiler can generate unified vectorized IR (say, making vector size always 4), and let the code generator deals with it (each code generator may need to merge or split vector operands). However, in implementation, giving an appropriate size to a vector operand is regarded as easier at the IR level than at the code generation level. So, I guess people gave up living in the world of "Ideas." Nonetheless, I believe that machine-independent optimizations could be referred as machine-independent yet.

You might need to ask what kind of fancy instructions the TA does not want to see. If that's only vector instructions, all vector-related flags should be disabled but you could use -O3. My example code could be used to see if there is still SIMD instructions:

```
$ gcc -O3 -S code.c
$ cat code.s | egrep xmm
```

If the output is empty, you are good.